# Issue with pop-ups on ios9/safari

Tags: javascript, alert, ios9

i have an application where i want alert box to continue popping up even if the user clicks "ok" for a certain period of time. But, with the new version of ios 9, the pop-ups are blocked after user gets 3 alert messages on the screen. How can i resolve this using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps making use of a custom alert or dialog would be a better approach than driving to beat the vendors expected behavior?